# Conditionally Render a Button

Tags: javascript

In my application I have the following object:

```
[
    {
        "field": "name",
        "lang": "it",
        "text": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "field": "name",
        "lang": "en",
        "text": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "field": "pdf_url",
        "lang": "en",
        "text": ""
    },
    {
        "field": "pdf_url",
        "lang": "it",
        "text": "/var/www/vhosts/www.mar.com/IT-Codice-di-Condotta-NEW-20221213205852072761.pdf"
    }
]
```

I want to conditionally render a button inside my JSX page. In order to do this I need to loop over the field named "pdf_url" for each language. At the moment English and Italian.
I wrote this code but it seem not to work. the function isDocumentUploaded returns true or false. Basically I need to check in the frontend is the file exists.
The mistake i am making is that i am not able to loop over the languages. I get only the first result.

```
{isDocumentUploaded(document?.translations?.find(translation => translation.field === 'pdf_url')?.text) ?

<DownloadButton onClick={() => handleFileDownload(document.id, obj.lang, obj.name)} />
 
:

<p className='text-red-500'><i className="ml-2 fa-lg text-red-500 fa-sharp fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i></p>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### TLDR:

Use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

---

#### The Problem

I agree the issue is that when you `.find()` a translation that has the `"pdf_url"` field, you only get one of your two languages:

```js
{
    "field": "pdf_url",
    "lang": "en",
    "text": ""
}
```

This is because the `.find()` method will return only the first match it "finds".

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

---

#### A Solution

An alternative to `.find()` that returns an array of matching elements is the `.filter()` method.

More [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a shallow copy of a portion of a given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Once you have an array of "pdf_url" field translations, you could then use the `.find()` method to track down the one with "text" e.g. `. . .translations?.filter(trans => trans.field === "pdf_url").find(trans => trans.text). . .`